# When creating an inventory, how do I keep people from adding a negative number?

Tags: ruby

I am creating a very simple "Repository" as my first real ruby script. I have  the sections created where people can create an item and starting value, but I cannot seem to nail down how to keep people from incrementing (or decrementing) by 0 or negative numbers.

My code to add is as follows:

```
class Item
 attr_accessor :name, :count
 def initialize (name,initCount )
 @name=name.downcase
 @count=initCount
end

def add(amount)
@count += amount
end

def sub(amount)
@count -= amount
end

end

def prompt()
puts @items.inspect
puts " (A)dd item\n (R)emove item\n (L)ist items\n (I)ncrease item\n (D)ecrease items\n (Q)uit "
select = [(print '?: '), gets.rstrip][1]


if (select.upcase=="A") then
puts "Add Item\nItem name"
name=[(print 'Name? : '), gets.rstrip][1]
puts "Initial Count"
count= [(print 'Count? : '), gets.rstrip][1]
@items.push(Item.new(name,count.to_i)) unless @items.index(@items.find { |l| l.name == name })

end
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is it pure Ruby or Rails?

Comment: Sorry @iceman. It's just ruby.

Comment: Please don't tag it with rails then, it's a different thing.

Comment: Sorry! I was advised by a teacher that we should tag as both. My bad, won't happen again.

Comment: You could add an if statement in the sub and add methods to check whether `amount` is a legal value `return if amount < 0` or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Consider organizing your code like this. I may have made a few errors, but you'll get the idea.

```
PROMPT_TEXT =
" (A)dd item
 (R)emove item
 (L)ist items
 (I)ncrease items
 (D)ecrease items
 (Q)uit ?: "

ILLEGAL_PROMPT_RESPONSE_MSG =
  "You can't enter that! What were you thinking??"
NEGATIVE_NUMBER_MSG =
  "If I've told you once, I've told you a thousand times: NO NEGATIVE NUMBERS!"
NOT_NUMBER_MSG =
  "If that's a number, it must be Roman, and they aren't allowed."
TRY_AGAIN_MSG = "Try again...
```

.

```
def prompt()
  loop do
    puts @items.inspect # What's this?
    puts PROMPT_TEXT
    gets.rstrip.upcase case
      when "A"
        break if add_item
      when "R"
        ...
      when "L"
        ...
      ...
      when "Q" then return
      else
        puts ILLEGAL_PROMPT_RESPONSE_MSG
      end
    puts TRY_AGAIN_MSG
  end
end
```

.

```
def add_item
  puts "Add Item\nItem name"
  print 'Name? : '
  name = gets.rstrip
  puts "Initial Count"
  print 'Count? : '
  count = gets.rstrip
  unless count =~ /\d+/
    if count =~ /-\s*\d+/
      puts NEGATIVE_NUMBER_MSG
    else
      puts NOT_NUMBER_MSG
    end
    return false
  end
  @items.push...
  true
end
```

Aside: the statement

```
name=[(print 'Name? : '), gets.rstrip][1]
```

brings to mind a word that begins with "abomin" and ends with "ation". :-)

Answer (score -1):

```
class Item
    attr_accessor :name, :count
    def initialize (name,initCount )
        raise if initCount<0

        @name=name.downcase
        @count=initCount
    end

    def add(amount)
        raise if amount<0

        @count += amount
    end

    def sub(amount)
        raise if amount<0 || amount>@count

        @count -= amount
    end

end
```

Comment: While using `raise` is a good start, it'd be better to not raise a generic Exception, but instead use something more specific, and say why the exception was raised. ArgumentError might be useful since the parameter `amount` is out of range.

Comment: Also, explain why your answer is useful. Throwing out code is like throwing a fish to the OP. Instead, explain why this is useful and educate so the OP knows how to fish.